# Jwebsocket : How to send the request to a specific client by name

Tags: javascript, java, websocket, java-websocket

I am trying to establish a connection between a single server and lots of clients(more than 100). I am using `websocket` for the client and `jwebsocket` for the server.

The clients should always stay connected and the server should send request to a specific client inlcuding the name of the client.

It works to send the request but I am not able to send the request to a specific client.
Please help.

Comment: Can you please provide some code?

Each client is connected through an unique session. You should pick the desired/specific client using his particular session and use it to send your message via it.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to reinvent a 40-year old application protocol.  You probably need either a chat or pub/sub (or similar) protocol that sits "over" WebSocket.  Kaazing, ActiveMQ, NodeJS, et al, have these protocols already implemented over WebSocket.  WebSocket is a transport; it is not a messaging system.